# image not getting display in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and create a webpage where I need to put a logo in it.

I'm trying to import the logo image but still not getting a display. can you please help me to understand where I'm wrong here?

my image path is /src/image/logo.png.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, Form, FormControl, NavDropdown, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { requirePropFactory } from '@material-ui/core';

const Styles = styled.div`
        
          .navbar { background-color: #c91010; }
          a, .navbar-nav, .navbar-light .nav-link {
            color: #222;
            &:hover { color: white; }
          }
          .navbar-brand {
            display :flex
            font-size: 1.4em;
            color: #222;
            &:hover { color: white; }
          }
          .form-center {
            position: absolute !important;
            left: 25%;
            right: 25%;
          }
        // `;
export const NavigationBar = () => (

  <Styles>

    <Navbar expand="lg">

      <Navbar.Brand href="/">
        <img src={require("/src/image/logo.png")}
          width="30"
          height="30"
          className="d-inline-block align-top"
          alt=" "
        />

      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Form className="form-center">
        <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="" />
      </Form>
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="ml-auto">
          <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  </Styles>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src={require("./src/image/logo.png")}
```

Try this.